# How to check if a newly created object is identical to an object inside of an array

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I know a newly declared identical object is still a different object. how can I check if "Points" array includes any object that is identical to that new object

```
const Points = [{ "latitude": 47.590868, "longitude": -122.336729 },
               { "latitude": 47.601604, "longitude": -122.336042 },
               { "latitude": 47.608490, "longitude": -122.342410 },]

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                var loc = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]
                var formattedLocation = {"latitude": loc[0], "longitude": loc[1]}
                
                if(Points.includes(formattedLocation)){  //PROBLEM IS HERE.
                    console.log(Points.includes(formattedLocation)) // will always return false
                    // I WANT THIS TO BE TRUE IF formattedLocation object is similar to any OBJECT inside 
                    of Points array
                }    
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), it will convert your object into a string, and then you can compare it

```js
const obj1 = { "latitude": 47.590868, "longitude": -122.336729 }
const obj2 = { "latitude": 47.590868, "longitude": -122.336729 }
console.log(obj1 === obj2) // false
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly compare two objects. The `.includes()` cannot check if the objects in the array has the same object provided. You can loop though the `Points` array to find a match.

```
var inLocation = false;
Points.forEach(point=>{
  if (point.latitude == formattedLocation.latitude && point.longitude == formattedLocation.longitude) inLocation = true;
})
if (inLocation) {
    // Do your stuffs
}
```